# Are these things vulnerable to JavaScript injection?

Tags: javascript, security

I have a few places where user input is displayed to other users.

An input box.

The value from that input box between `<p>` tags.

The value from that input box between `<a>` tags.

Pretty much it's a form that a user enters in a display name, and then you get two spots on next page where the name is displayed between the two tags. Certain users can go back and edit this textbox.

If a user enters in 'hello world', the next user will see a textbox prepopualted with 'hello world', as well as `<a href="#">hello world</a> <p>hello world</p>`

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript or JavaScript security. Is this vulnerable to an attack in some way? If so what should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Usually your mantra should be: filter input, escape output. **Filter input** means that you should reject all non valid user input, **escape output** means that you should always properly escape the user input that you show so that, in the event that filtering fails, it would still do no harm.

Comment: Yes. You need to encode data for whatever system it's going to be used in. This is true for everything, ever. You should never count on filtering input to save you. Don't filter input for security reasons, ever. Always encode output correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this opens up a possible XSS vulnerability.

You should use the `.innerText` property of the node you wish to populate with user content.

```
var node = document.getElementById('foo');
node.innerText = 'whatever the user entered';
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how it's vulnerable?

Comment: @user1652427 Someone could write `<script>JS code to send cookies somewhere else</script>`.

Comment: <script>alert('test')</script> doesn't seem to do anything though. Should it?

Comment: All it does is take the value of the input box and put it between <p> and <a> tags.

Comment: Even if it doesn't lead to actual JavaScript code being executed, the fact is that some tags shouldn't be there, e.g. `<strong>hello</strong>` would be shown in bold.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is vulnerable to XSS attacks, have a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A2